# Oracle SQL placement of a where statement in simple join query

Tags: sql, oracle

this query does not work -

```
select userprofile.username, userprofile.deskid , desk.deskname
from userprofile 
where userprofile.username in ('user1', 'user2', "user3')
inner join desk on userprofile.deskid = desk.deskid
```

this query does  - is did not change anything, all i dis was change the order of the component parts of the query statement. It had to do with the position of the where clause

```
select userprofile.username, userprofile.deskid , desk.deskname
from userprofile 
inner join desk on userprofile.deskid = desk.deskid 
where userprofile.username in ('user1', 'user2', 'user3')
```

I am not really understanding why putting the where statement at the end of the query fixed the output.

Comment: The first query won't even run. It's simply invalid syntax

Comment: SQL syntax requires all of the bits of the FROM clause come before the WHERE clause. It's just the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some thing about SQL syntax that you do not understand.

A `SELECT` statement consists of a set of clauses, in a fixed order.  The most common clauses are:

- `SELECT`
- `FROM`
- `WHERE`
- `GROUP BY`
- `HAVING`
- `ORDER BY`

The order is fixed.  The `WHERE` clause (if present) always follows the `FROM` clause.  `JOIN` is an *operator* recognized in the `FROM` clause.  It is not a clause, which is why your first version does not work.

I have a rather strict indentation policy on any query that I write.  I always left align the clauses and generally put operators at the *end* of a line.  That is why I would write the query as:

```
select u.username, u.deskid, d.deskname
from userprofile u join
     desk d
     on u.deskid = d.deskid 
where u.username in ('user1', 'user2', 'user3')
```

Note that I also use table aliases, which make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: Hey - thank you  - I know nothing about SQL  - I got downvoted but I am sure someone else  in my position will get something out of it.  - good work -- your explanation adds value